# Name of the Quartic Surface $z=(x^2-a^2)(y^2-a^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, surfaces, quartics

Does the surface defined by the following equation have an specific name?
$$ f(x,y)=(x^2-a^2)(y^2-a^2)$$

I've searched a lot and found that $z=x^2y^2$ is called [Crossed Trough](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossedTrough.html). However I didn't find any names for the aforementioned function.

Comment: Note that this is: $(x-a)(x+a)(y-a)(y+a)$.

Comment: @lightxbulb So it seems it is not a crossed trough.

Comment: If $a=0$ then you have the crossed trough. If $a \neq 0$ then I don't know the name, but: if you view $z$ as a parameter (or look at the cross-sections with planes $z=c$) then at $z=0$ you have the "#" union of four lines $x=\pm a, y = \pm a$, for $z>0$ the intersections are "smoothed out" one way and for $z<0$ the intersections are smoothed out another way.

Comment: @RicardoBuring Thanks for your reply. But what do you mean by "smoothing"?

Comment: @SMA.D You convinced me to learn how to make animations in SageMath (to illustrate what I mean): https://imgur.com/a/59y6m5k

Comment: @Ricardo Buring: if you have time, maybe you could write a tutorial to your animation?